# Geotargeting: Multiple subdirectories for same language

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2

Is it reasonable to create multiple stores i.e.
[site].com/uk/
[site].com/scot/
[site].com/ie/

For the purpose of taking advantage of webmaster tools geotargeting features to rank better in those countries?

Further - Is it a good idea to create others for countries with high english speaking populations without the intention of translating product descriptions? i.e.
[site].com/no/
[site].com/nl/